# White space at the top + links not centered

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am trying to figure out how to not have the white space at the top and to the right(it's a small little white line there but i can still notice it).
Also, my links don't seem to align in the center when i resize the browser to under 1000px. They are centered while>1000px.

[image]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v3jxeo5/1/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
  .navbar {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    width: 40%;
  }
}

.buttonsTop {
  text-align: center;
  outline-color: blue;
  outline-width: 1px;
  outline-style: inset;
}

.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  outline-color: red;
  outline-width: 1px;
  outline-style: inset;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: red;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  -ms-transition: all .5s;
  transform: scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="topImage">
  <div class="buttonsTop">
    <div class="navbar"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
    <div class="navbar"><a href="#aboutmeSection">About Me</a></div>
    <div class="navbar"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></div>
    <div class="navbar"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The white space on the top and right is due to a margin on the `body`. As for the links not being centered, you have a media query that sets them to `display: block;` for screen sizes below 1000px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code a bit. hope this helps. I haven't cleaned up your code. Please make use of some reset CSS or write one yourself to reset the user-agent styles

```css
.buttonsTop{
  text-align: center;
  outline-color:blue;
  outline-width:1px;
    outline-style:inset;
}
.navbar{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;  
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
}
.navbar a{
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 12px;
 text-decoration: none;   
 -moz-transition: all 1s;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s;
 -o-transition: all 1s;
 -ms-transition: all 1s; 
outline-color:red;
outline-width:1px;
outline-style:inset;    
}
.navbar a:hover {
 color:  red;
 -moz-transition: all .5s;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
 -o-transition: all .5s;
 -ms-transition: all .5s;
     
 transform : scale(1.3);
 -moz-transform : scale(1.3);
 -webkit-transform : scale(1.3);
 -o-transform : scale(1.3);
 -ms-transform : scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
     .buttonsTop {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
      }
     .navbar{       
        display:block;
        width: 40%;
     }  
    .navbar a{
        float: none;       
    }
     
}
</style>
<title> MySite </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class= "topImage">
<div class="buttonsTop">
 <div class= "navbar"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
 <div class= "navbar"><a href="#aboutmeSection">About Me</a></div>
 <div class= "navbar"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></div>
 <div class= "navbar"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
   </div>
 
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It did help with the white space at the top, but i want the buttons to show in a list like in this picture [link](https://imgur.com/a/IIueW6l). Using display:inline-block instead makes them look like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/ksY2BSn) which is not the look i'm going for. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @Markt Keeping it back to block might fix your issue. I have updated the code.

Comment: @Markt Glad that worked!!. Can you please accept the answer if that helped?